# R: Replacing NA by group table

Tags: r, dplyr, imputation

I'm about to split my dataframe into a train and test part for training a machine learning algorithm. In doing so, I need to replace NA values of the training set, keep them and apply them later on the test set. This is a common method, so that no test data influences the training.

A key point is, that a have data that belongs to certain groups, e.g. a gender. Therefore the imputation of data must be based on the groups. Here is an example dataframe:

```
df <- dplyr::tibble(gender  = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2), 
                    lab1 = c(NA, 2, 3, NA, NA),
                    lab2 = c(4, NA, NA, 2, 2))
```

As a next step, I computed the following table based on other data with the same shape (training data). This is the output:

```
  gender col   imputed_with
   <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
1      1 lab1             3
2      2 lab1             2
3      1 lab2             3
4      2 lab2             2
```

I now need to replace the missing values in the first dataframe with the values here in this table which basically serves as a lookup table, computed with the training data.

How can this be achieved? Or better, is there any official package that can facilitate the whole imputation process?

Answer (score 0):

To combine the two tables, you need a coalescing join, which you can achieve with `tidyr::pivot_longer()` and `dplyr::rows_patch()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tibble(
  gender  = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2), 
  lab1 = c(NA, 2, 3, NA, NA),
  lab2 = c(4, NA, NA, 2, 2)
)

to_impute <- tibble::tribble(
  ~gender, ~col, ~imputed_with,
  1, "lab1", 3,
  2, "lab1", 2,
  1, "lab2", 3,
  2, "lab2", 2
)

impute_wide <- pivot_wider(
  to_impute, 
  names_from = col, 
  values_from = imputed_with
)

impute_wide
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   gender  lab1  lab2
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1      1     3     3
#> 2      2     2     2

rows_patch(
  df, 
  impute_wide, 
  by = colnames(to_impute)[!colnames(to_impute) %in% c("col", "imputed_with")]
)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   gender  lab1  lab2
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1      1     3     4
#> 2      2     2     2
#> 3      1     3     3
#> 4      1     3     2
#> 5      2     2     2
```

However, there are plenty of R packages that deal with imputation.

If you're familiar with the `tidymodels` packages, then the `recipes::step_impute_()` family of functions are useful for imputation, while stopping data leakage from the test set to the train set.

In the mice package, `mice::mice()` has an `ignore` parameter, which allows you to ignore the testing part of a dataset while fitting an imputation model.

I'm sure there are others that I'm not aware of too.